# How should I tile images for CATiledLayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, cocoa-touch, catiledlayer

I know **how** to tile images, I just don't get how the images should turn out, with sizes and stuff..

The names should be Image_size_row_colum, and one of the Apple tiles images is:
Lake_125_0_0.png

I use TileCutter to tile the images, but I don't know if I should tile my original image to 512x512px, and then make a worse resolution image of the original from ≈7000x6000 to ≈5000x4000 and then tile that image to 512x512px or whatever.. I just don't get the whole setup..

The class reads images like this:

```
NSString *tileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d_%d_%d", 
                                     imageName, (int)(scale * 1000), row, col];
```

And with the first of apples tiles are named Lake_125_0_0.png, that gives me nothing.. I just don't get it.. Anyone?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tiles are by default always 256 to 256 pixels (although in the apple example some tiles at the border of the image got cropped).

Lake_1000_1_2: full resolution tile at scale 1, row 1, col 2.

Lake_500_1_2:  half resolution: the tile is also 256 to 256 pixel but you show an area of the image which is actually 512 to 512 pixels (so you loose quality)

Lake_250_1_2:  quarter resolution

Lake_125_1_2:  show 8*256 to 8*256 pixels of the original image inside a 256 to 256 pixels tile

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah I get it! So the _1000, _500 etc is like a thousandths? 1000/1000 full scale, 500/1000 half etc.. I thought it had something to do with the actual resolution, so I had tried to scale my image with 5000x4000 and name it Image_5000 with no luck. Thank you!:)

Comment: when you zoom out to scale 1/2 it asks for the images with _500, when you zoom out to scale 1/4 you get the images with _250, ...

the photoscroller sample from apple forces the zoomscale to be 1, 0.5, 0.25 or 0.125.